# jQuery UI's "datepicker" modules date cant be saved to MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, date

I have the format of the date returned from Datepicker as (yy-mm-dd) which returns the string as 2011-04-22.

When I want to INSERT it in the MySQL table in the column with datatype as DATE, I get 0000-00-00 saved. Browsing through SO, I found suggestions about FROM_UNIXTIME, but this gives me the date as 1970-01-01.

Any help ?

Comment: can you post your code where you build your query?

Comment: 1970-01-01 is the earliest time allowed by UNIXTIME it is essentially equivalent to 0000-00-00. You just have to make sure the formatting of the string your outputting marries up with the date format in MYSQL

Comment: Not true.  You can use negative timestamp numbers to get dates earlier than the Unix Epoch of 1970-01-01

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try with dateFormat option in datepicker

```
$('#date-picker').datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

If you want to give custom formats in view, you may need to convert the date to mysql format before inserting to the database. `

```
$insertDate  = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date))`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that the datatype is setup as a MySQL DATE field (as opposed to a DATETIME field which requires the time formatted like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

Also, the MySQL DATE datatype is looking for a 4-digit year field where you have a 2 digit field, so make sure you have Date Picker output as yyyy-mm-dd.

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Also, If you are trying to get this going with unix timestamps, don't forget that Unix Timestamps in Javascript include milliseconds where in PHP/MySQL they are truncated to seconds.  So if you do use FROM_UNIXTIME(time) in MySQL, make sure you divide the timestamp by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery UI datepicker also has a native parse method you can use to change a string into a date. The string needs to be formatted correctly already for this to work.

```
$.datepicker.parseDate( "yy-mm-dd", "2007-01-26" );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an even simpler way download the file jquery-ui.js from

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js

go to line 3041

```
dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
```

Change it to your desired result i.e. yy/mm/dd and its done

```
dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd/",
```